# Помогите кодом для автозаполнения

Tags: mysql

Создаю базу и стандартных функций не достаточно. Хочется авто заполнение реализовать. Т.е. есть таблица на форме и строчка. В таблице заготовленные ответы в столбик, и при нажатии на ответ должен автоматически перенестись в строку через запятую. Строка в свою очередь должна быть редактируемой.

второе авто заполнение, когда выбираешь из списка в строке, автоматически заполнялась другая строка из базы, т.е фио и телефон или как почти на всех сайтах при вводе почтового ящика. Вводится имя и телефон.

Comment: Не понятно написано всё.
Но как я понял тут нужен php или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: можно использовать триггер на вставку